# If-else condition does not work as per expectation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, if-statement, razor

If-else condition is not working in the view page.

In my view page in two table data

- tbl_career
- tbl_vacancy

currently, tbl_career is empty. So I want to display **currently no content available**.
currently tbl_vacancy is having 2 records.

Output:

[image]

HomeController.cs:

```
        public ActionResult Index(tbl_carrer _Carrer)
        {

            var model = new CarrerViewModal
            {

                tbl_Carrers = _dbfltEntities.tbl_carrer.ToList(),

                tbl_Qetintouches = _dbfltEntities.tbl_qetintouch.ToList(),

            };

            //if (_Carrer == null)
            //{
            //    ViewBag.message = "No Content Available";
            //}

            return View(model);
        }
```

ViewModal:

```
namespace flatAd.Models
{
    public class CarrerViewModal
    {
        public List<tbl_carrer> tbl_Carrers { get; set; }
        public List<tbl_qetintouch> tbl_Qetintouches { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model flatAd.Models.CarrerViewModal

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Show Career Data</h2>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>UserCarrerID</th>
            <th>UserEmailID</th>
            <th>UserContactNo</th>
            <th>UserResume</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        @foreach (var itemcarrer in Model.tbl_Carrers)
        {
            if (Model != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@itemcarrer.usercarrerid</td>
                    <td>
                        @itemcarrer.useremailid
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @itemcarrer.usercontactno
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        itemcarrer.userresume
                    </td>
                </tr>


            }

            else
            {

                <tr>
                    <td><label>Content Not Available</label></td>
                </tr>

            }
        }

    </tbody>

</table>

<h2>Show GetInTouch Data</h2>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>EmailId</th>
            <th>PhoneNo</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var itemgetintouch in Model.tbl_Qetintouches)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@itemgetintouch.name</td>
            <td>
                @itemgetintouch.emailid
            </td>
            <td>
                @itemgetintouch.phonenumber
            </td>
            <td>
                @itemgetintouch.description
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

What I am trying:

- **list is providing the count variable but also not working**

```
        @foreach (var itemcarrer in Model.tbl_Carrers)  
        {  
            if (Model.tbl_Carrers.Count == 0)  
            {  
                <tr>  
                    <td><label>Content Not Available</label></td>  
                </tr> 
            }  
  
            else  
            {  
                <tr>  
                    <td>@itemcarrer.usercarrerid</td>  
                    <td>  
                        @itemcarrer.useremailid  
                    </td>  
                    <td>  
                        @itemcarrer.usercontactno  
                    </td>  
                    <td>  
                        @itemcarrer.userresume  
                    </td>  
                </tr>  
            }  
  
        }
```

**I am trying the following as well, but it's also not working:**

```
@*@if (Model == null)  
    {  
        <tr>  
            <td><label>Content Not Available</label></td>  
        </tr>  
    }*@  
@*else  
    {  
  
  
    foreach (var itemcarrer in Model.tbl_Carrers)  
    {  
    <tr>  
        <td>@itemcarrer.usercarrerid</td>  
        <td>  
            @itemcarrer.useremailid  
        </td>  
        <td>  
            @itemcarrer.usercontactno  
        </td>  
        <td>  

            @itemcarrer.userresume  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    }  
  
    }*@
```

The following condition is also not working:

```
        @foreach (var itemcarrer in Model.tbl_Carrers)
        {
            if (Model.tbl_Carrers != null)
            {
                 <tr>
                    <td>@itemcarrer.usercarrerid</td></tr>
            } 
            else
            {
                <tr>
                    <td><label>Content Not Available</label></td>
                </tr> 
            }
```

Is any thing wrong with the *if-else* condition?

Comment: @Salah Akbari thanks for answer and explaination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`If` works. Any code *inside* a `foreach` loop won't get executed if there are no data. The `if` in this loop will never run if `tbl_Carrers` is empty.

```
@foreach (var itemcarrer in Model.tbl_Carrers)  
{  
    if (Model.tbl_Carrers.Count == 0)  
    {
    }  
 ...
```

The check and loop should be reversed:

```
if (Model.tbl_Carrers.Count == 0)  
{
    <tr>  
        <td colspan="4"><label>Content Not Available</label></td>  
    </tr> 
}  
else
{
    foreach(.....)
    {
    }
}
```

Notice the `colspan` attribute. Without it, the label would appear in the first column only

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said, you need to find a way to check for `tbl_Carrers`, but it seems in your code you have check for `Model` itself, don't forget that `Model` is `CarrerViewModal` in your case. With that being said the following line shouldn't work since you've checked for `Model` itself:

```
@foreach (var itemcarrer in Model.tbl_Carrers)
{
    if (Model != null)
```

In the following line you've check for `tbl_Carrers` but the foreach code is not running at all as you don't have enough data in your `tbl_Carrers` so the `if` condition is not executed again:

```
@foreach (var itemcarrer in Model.tbl_Carrers)  
{  
    if (Model.tbl_Carrers.Count == 0)
```

So what you need is something like this:

```
if (Model.tbl_Carrers.Count == 0)  
{
    <tr>  
        <td><label>Content Not Available</label></td>  
    </tr> 
}  

else
{
    //iterating through data using the foreach loop
}
```